# Silverlight application for learning purpose

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I saw this work which looked very good. Someone tell me or share your knowledge how to accomplish this.

http://www.moshafy.com/

Things want to know like.

1 - Has he used DB to load all the arabic scripts. Because these are not images or static text?

2 - How he has achived flipping of page?

3 -

Your feedback on making this kind of work like
how to mange scripts?
what should be image and what should be text from db?
What if I want to add soud on the script when user select word or line?
Any tutorials specific to quickly learn that kind of functionality?
Anything you can share to help me explore more on that path.

Also posted here [Silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/215633.aspx) but couldn't get much help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 - Stored the scripts as unicode in a DB or localized the application specifically for his language using the resource files (localization/globalication/CultureInfo)

2 - This can be achieved using TransitioningContentControl from SL Toolkit, aditinally there are commercial controls available that act as "book pages" too.

3 - storing the scripts as text is probably a more optimal solution then loading images, if you use images in your project, your .xap file's size will increase - thus the load time will be longer. As far as sound goes, media playback is possible in Silverlight, I've only tried with WMV files but I think mp3s are supported as well - if not WMA is probably supported.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are 2 things in my mind. If I click on complete WORD than it should be selected and produce a sound for that selected word. Any comments on that?

Comment: Well, one way to do it would be to create transparent TextBox that would have IsReadOnly set to true, TextBoxes permit text selection while TextBlocks don't. Since nothing is impossible - I suppose creating a selectable TextBlock is possible too, but I'd need to look it up.